# Are open sets of a product space necessarily given by the Cartesian product of two open sets?

Tags: general-topology

Given two topological spaces $(X,\mathcal U)$ and $(Y, \mathcal V)$, the product topology on $X\times Y$ is that given by the basis $\mathcal B=\{U\times V: U\in \mathcal U, V\in\mathcal V\}$.

But this is a particular topology in $X\times Y$. In general, if we have an open set $Z$ of $X\times Y$, does $Z=U\times V$ for some $U\in\mathcal U$ and $V\in\mathcal V$?

Comment: No. For example, the product topology of $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$ is the same as the Euclidean topology on $\mathbb R^2$, but the basis for the product topology does not contain all open subsets of $\mathbb R^2$ - they are "too boxy." In particular, an open disk in $\mathbb R^2$ can't be in $\mathcal B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An open set $W$ in the product topology is in the basis $\mathcal B$ if and only if:

> For all $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)\in W$, we have that $(x_1,y_2),(x_2,y_1)\in W$.

But it is not hard to find, in most cases[*], that there is some pair $W_1=U_1\times V_1$ and $W_2=U_2\times V_2$ such that $W_1\cup W_2$ does not have this property.

[*] I say "in most cases," because in a few cases, like $|Y|=1$, this is not true.